# Nice syntax for function composition in Scala

Tags: scala

I would like to arrive to a syntax as productive as Haskell's `desort = (reverse . sort)` in Scala... Here is my attempt:

```
implicit class Composition[A,B,C](val g: A => B) {
  def o(f: B => C): A => C = { a:A => f(g(a))}
}

val fg = cos _ o sin
```

Is there any way we can get rid of the `_`in the declaration of gf?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For functions yes, but for methods, no. Your problem is that you're trying to use a method for `g`, and not a function. For functions, there is already a method for this called `andThen`:

```
val f: Int => Int = _ + 1
val g: Int => String = _.toString

scala> val fg = f andThen g
fg: Int => String = <function1>

scala> fg(2)
res3: String = 3
```

Your own implicit class will work as well (though I haven't looked at the exact semantics you desire), using functions like `f` and `g`, as I've defined them. It will even work for a function and a method (in that order).

```
def a(i: Int): Int = i + 1
def b(i: Int): String = i.toString

scala> f andThen a
res4: Int => Int = <function1>
```

However, `a andThen b` does not work as-is, because `a` is a method, which you cannot call `andThen` on. In order to use `andThen`, `a` needs to be converted to a function, which will not happen automatically, because a function isn't necessarily expected. `a _ andThen b` eta-expands `a` into a function, in which has a method called `andThen`, and can be provided an argument of `b` (a method), because the compiler will implicitly convert `b` to a function, since a function is the only thing that is expected as an argument of `andThen`. `Function` isn't the only type with a method called `andThen`, so the compiler can't expect one 100% of the time to make the conversion from method to function for `a`.